# "Appreciate Answer" feature for visitors or users

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes when I visit sites for something specific thing I seen "Is it helpful?" link but I never hit it as yes or no. When people searching for something specific and if they will found in Stack Exchange then they'd prefer it , Even when I found something helpful with SE sometimes I'm glad as I'd like to appreciate it ; so I'm thinking if there were feature like "Is it helpful?". But also I'm thinking as for just nice appreciable question and answer ; otherwise they'll mess it with unanswered questions and incomplete answers. Only with positive perspect . "Appreciate Answer". Sounds so much but wish I could see it.

Comment: You can already appreciate answers by upvoting them. Other than that, I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're unregistered or without enough reputation to vote, clicking a vote button still does something. The feedback really is stored. Moderators and >10K users have access to a ["post feedback" information page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121936/295684). There, they can see - for example - questions that are voted up much higher by real votes than by anonymous/low-rep feedback.

If you really liked a question, you can [star it as a favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/295684) regardless of how much reputation you have. Admittedly, this doesn't really affect anything other than letting you easily find the question again and possibly giving the question owner a badge.

I see you're getting close to 200 reputation on one site. Once you get there, you'll receive the association bonus (+100 on every Stack Exchange site you join), which will enable you to, among other things, comment and vote up.

Comment: The "Post Feedback" page no longer exists ... [Post Feedback link is broken](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/209787)

Comment: @DavidPostill On Stack Overflow, it is indeed gone, but weirdly enough, `/tools/post-feedback` still works on all the other places I can check, including Super User.